# How to integrate other pages into laravel pre-built authentication

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

After reading some tutorials on laravel 5.4 authentication (including the doc),I don't know how to work with it in my file.
I have been able to run the artisan command.. php artisan make:auth. Have seen the the controller, views etc that was created and even have accessed it by going to http://localhost/blogsite/public/register (don't worry about, its on my local disk) but how do I integrate it with with the pages that needs authentication? That I don't know..

Who can put me through how to integrate it with other pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many way you can use for this solution. 
First Way: 
If you load views file from controller just use the following line to your controller. 
 **Suppose** my controller name is `DashBoardController`

```
public function __construct()
{
     $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

So all of the `view` you return from `DashboardController` it will make you `auth` for you. That means if you return any of `view` from this `controller` you must need to log in.

So you need to put this constructor function to all of your `Controller` from where you return `view` and need to authenticate the user.

To avoid this constructor funtion to all controller you can use the following 
 Way using `route`:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::Your_Request_Method('your_url1', 'YourController1');
    Route::Your_Request_Method('your_url2', 'YourController2');
});
```

You can get more way at **[laravel authentication documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication)**

Hope you will understand.